# flutter CircularprogressIndicator keeps on crashing

Tags: flutter

i am trying to create a loading screen but once I add this code the progressindicator disappears and forms an x on the screen once I add this line of code

```
 @override
  void initState() {
    _loadUserInfo();
    super.initState();
  }
```

this is the entire flutter class

```
import 'package:blog_project/screens/home.dart';
import 'package:blog_project/service/constant.dart';
import 'package:blog_project/service/user_service.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'login.dart';

class Loading extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoadingState createState() => _LoadingState();
}

class _LoadingState extends State<Loading> {
  late BuildContext _context;
  void _loadUserInfo() async {
    String token = await getToken();
    if (token == '') {
      Navigator.of(_context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_context) => Login()), (route) => false);
    } else {
      ApiResponse response = await getUserDetail();
      if (response.error == null) {
        Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Home()), (route) => false);
      } else if (response.error == unauthorized) {
        Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Login()), (route) => false);
      } else {
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
          content: Text('${response.error}'),
        ));
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    _loadUserInfo();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
      color: Colors.white,
      child: const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please try to run `super.initState();` first and then `_loadUserInfo()`?

Comment: object construction, initState, and build() must *all* be sync and fast.  You're trying to do something async in initState, and it will not be complete before build() begins.  Look in to using FutureBuilder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it because your "_context" is not initialized when '_loadUserInfo()' is called.

> late BuildContext _context;

You don't need to define '_context' to use it in the '_loadUserInfo()' function.
If you want using context in initState, just use WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((call) to ensure that the context is available and the widget tree has been fully built, and replace _context with context inside _loadUserInfo

```
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();

  WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((call) {
    _loadUserInfo();
  });
}

void _loadUserInfo() async {
  String token = await getToken();
  if (token == '') {
    Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Login()), (route) => false);
  } else {
  ... 
  }
}
```